# Telegram bot sendMessage() is deprecated in java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, бот

Если этот метод уже deprecated, то как лучше отправлять сообщения клиенту?

[image: Пример кода]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод попал в `Deprecated` с версии 3.2: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Changelog

Там же сказано, как мигрировать на новую версию библиотеки:

> To version 3.2
>
> 1. Replace usage of all deprecated methods from AbsSender with methods execute or executeAsync.
> 2. If you are extending AbsSender class, implement new added methods.

То есть просто замените `sendMessage` на `execute`, если у вас нет никакой мудреной логики. `execute` теперь принимает wildcard generic, а объект `SendMessage` как раз подходит под этот wildcard.

P.S. Официальную документацию с changelogами полезно читать, рекомендую. Если разработчики что-то объявили `Deprecated`, то они непременно должны где-то написать что же делать теперь. Либо в javadocs, либо на сайте в changelogs, например.

Comment: Спасибо, в javadoc ничего не пишут, буду читать документацию.