# Telegram bot api. Нужно получить текст из следующего сообщения (java)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Пользователь вводит команду /setzavtra, бот присылает сообщение с примером как нужно вводить данные и ждёт следующего сообщения, получив записывает в переменную.
Вопрос заключается в том как получить новое сообщение? В документации к api видел метод getUpdates, но во-первых я не знаю нужен ли он мне, а во-вторых я его просто не могу вызвать.

```
 public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Tomorrow lessons = new Tomorrow();
    Message message = update.getMessage();
    if(message != null && message.hasText())
    {
       switch(message.getText()) {
           case "/setzavtra":
               sendMsg(message, "Введите информацию в следующем виде: "+"\n"+lessons.Example());//через метод класса показываю как должен выглядеть ввод
               //хочу считать текст следующего сообщения, но не знаю как
               break;
           default:
               sendMsg(message, "Я - бот");
               break;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я пытался получить новое сообщение таким способом:
Message newmess = update.getMessage();

Но, ожидаемо получал тоже сообщение т.е. /setzavtra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `onUpdateReceived(Update update)` обрабатывает все входящие сообщения (обновления), не различая было ли оно "следующим" или каким то еще. Их селекцию нужно делать уже внутри метода. Например через `Map <текст входящего обновления, ответ>`. Если текст обновления совпадает с каким либо ключом - дается конкретный ответ, в противном случае предлагается ввести запрос в необходимом формате. Или вынесите логику ответов в отдельный класс,

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    try {
        sendMessage(message, messageFactory.createMessage(update));
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        //обработать исключение, например записать в лог
    }
}
```

в котором может храниться любая информация, в том числе предыдущие записи диалогов с любым пользователем. Анализируйте переписку и давайте подходящий ответ не трогая методы самого бота.

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент функция `sendMessage()` является устаревшей. На замену ей пришла `execute()`.[Вот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775401/telegram-bot-sendmessage-is-deprecated-in-java), где уже об этом говориться.
Дальше пишется:

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Message message = update.getMessage();
    try {
         sendMsg(message, "Чем я могу помочь?"););
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}


public void sendMsg(Message message, String s) throws TelegramApiException
{
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
    sendMessage.setText(s);
    execute(sendMessage);        
}
```